# How to enable BR tag after new line in textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a `textarea` and I want to put `<br/>` after every enter because I put the data in database. In database looks like this:

```
<pre>
  Text
  Text2
  Text3
</pre>
```

The output in the page looks like

```
<pre>
  TextTex2Tex3
</pre>
```

What can I do to put `<br/>` if is clicked enter.. or if exist another solution.

Answer (score 1):

When outputting the saved content, you can use the CSS rule `white-space: pre;` on the element that will contain the content of the `textarea`.

It's also safer than just outputting plain HTML content from your database.

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this

```
echo str_replace("\n","<br>",$your_value);
```

you would get your result

Comment: But I get my data with JS var html = "<u class='title-google-maps'>" + name + "</u> <p class='google-maps'>" + category + "</p>" + address + "<p class='google-maps'>" + phone + "</p>" + "<p class='google-maps-3'>" + schedule + "</p>" +  "<a class='google-maps' id='aflamulte' href=''>" + afla + "</a>";